# Webservice with always in memory object with queue

Tags: web-services, azure, queue, signalr

I have a function to give recommendations to users. This function need to make a lot of calcs to start, but after start it use the already calculed matrix on memory. After this, any other calc that is made, "fills" the object in memory to continuous learning.
My intention is to use this function to website users, but the response need to come from the same "object" in memory and need to be sequential by request because it is not thread safe.
How is the best way to get this working? My first idea was use signalr so the user dont need to wait to response and a queue to send the requests to objects. But how the signalr can receive the response for this specific request?
The entire flow is:
User enter on a page.
A javascript will call a service with the user ID and actual page.
The server will queue the ID an page.
The service will be calculating the results for each request on queue and sending responses.
The server will "receive" the response and send back to client.

The main problem is that I dont see a way to the service receive the response to send back to client until it is complete, without need to be looping in queues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use SignalR, I would suggest using a hub method to accept these potentially long running requests from the client. By doing so it should be obvious "how the signalr can receive the response for this specific request".

You should be able to queue your calculations from inside your hub method where you will have access to the caller's connection id (via the `Context.ConnectionId` property).

If you can await the results of your queued operation inside of the hub method you queue from, you can then simply return the result from your hub method and SignalR will flow the result back to the calling JavaScript. You can also use `Clients.Caller....` to send the result back.

If you go this route I suggest you use async/await instead of blocking request threads waiting for your long-running calculations to complete.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server

---

If you can't process your calculation results from the same method you queued the calculation from, you still have options. Just be sure to queue the caller's connection id and a request id along with the calculation to be processed.

Then, you can process the results of all your calculations from outside of your hub using `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext`:

```
private IHubContext _context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>()

// Call ProcessResults whenever results are ready to send back to the client
public void ProcessResults(string connectionId, uint requestId, MyResult result)
{
    // Presumably there's JS code mapping request id's to results
    // if you can have multiple ongoing requests per client
    _context.Clients.Client(connectionId).receiveResult(requestId, result);
}
```

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub